# Redeploy SP applications

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, migration, solution-deployment

I am carrying out a migration from one AD to another. 
I have matching versions and have dismounted and moved the original databases over.

Now I'm looking at restoring the applications.

If, in the shell, I run get-spsolution, I can see there are 7 solutions, only one of which deployed is true, so i need to redeploy these apps. Great.

I have taken the solutionID of the first app and tried

```
 install-spsolution e809e62-4a1b-4757-8ad0-blahblah -GACDeployment
```

It errors immediately and tells me that

> This solution contains resources scoped for a Web application and must be deployed to one or more web applications.

I suspect this may mean I have to get the re-deploy order correct, but that is, at best, an uneducated guess.

Can one of you fine people point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to mention the web application name in your command like this

```
Install-spsolution e809e62-4a1b-4757-8ad0-blahblah -WebApplication "URL of webapplication" -GACDeployment
```

Or you can use `-AllWebapplications` instead of webapplication if more than one web application in farm.

Test it now.